# question about group actions on metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, group-actions, geometric-group-theory

Suppose we have a metric space $V$, a group $G$ and an action $\cdot: G \times V \rightarrow V$.

What assumptions must I make so that the following is true?

Claim: For each $x, y \in V$, if there exists $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset G$, such that $g_n \cdot x \rightarrow y$ (i.e. $d(g_n \cdot x, y) \rightarrow 0)$, then $\text{Orb}(x) = \text{Orb}(y)$.

I do have available that for each $g \in G$, the map $x \mapsto g \cdot x$ is an isometry. So this is in common the wikipedia page on geometric group actions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_group_action, however, I don't think the groups I'm working with are finitely generated.

I'm not very well versed in algebra or topology, but this popped up in something I was working on.

In my particular context, I am working on a normed vector space $V$ so that $\text{Orb}(0) = \{0\}$, I'm not sure if this helps. It seems that $G$ needs to be some sort of topological group, but one of the vector spaces/groups I am working with, $V = L^1(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ and $G = \text{Aut}(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ (i.e. measurable bijections that preserve pushforward measure), doesnt seem to have an inherent topology nor is finitely generated.

Best

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Sorry maybe I  should write it differently. I just meant to say that for each $x,y \in G$, if there exists a sequence $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset G$ such that $d(g_n \cdot x, y) \rightarrow 0$, then $\text{Orb}(x) = \text{Orb}(y)$. I can edit this into my post.

Comment: You are asking about condition equivalent to "every orbit is closed". For finite dimensional continuous faithful linear isometric actions this is equivalent to compactness of $G$. For infinite dimensional representations, I do not think there is a non-tautological interpretation.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah yes the every orbit is closed immediately implies this. The rest of what you said was quite the mouthful and I had know idea what those words meant haha. I will have to dig deeper into this. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I just found out about the compact open topology and how if $X$ is a metric space, it makes $\text{Aut}(X)$ into a topological space in which case the topology is equivalent to compact convergence, which is nice since my $X = [0,1]^2$. Then I could give $\text{Aut}(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ the subspace topology and maybe there is something I could say about the orbits being closed when $X$ is a compact metric space.

Comment: Compact-open topology is useless for your purposes, you should be using the topology of $L^1$-convergence. Most likely, every $G$-orbit is closed in this setting, provided $G=Aut(X,\mu)$ and $\mu$ is a probability measure.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I didn't really understand your comment here. I meant that I could metrize $\text{Aut}(X)$ with uniform convergence. I don't think that an integral for a function $f:X \rightarrow X$ can be defined if $X$ is just a metric space.